# Minifilter Driver, Memory Map and Notepad

Tags: windows, driver, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping, minifilter

I'll start with my final goal.
I want that every document (doc,docx,pdf,txt, etc.) on my system will have a fixed (and transperent to the user) header.
For example, the string "abcde" will be prepended in every document.

In order to do so I wrote a minifilter driver that does the following:

`IRP_MJ_WRITE` - if header exists change offset to start of file.

`IRP_MJ_READ` - if header exists change offset to start of file.

`IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION` - if header exists change returned size of file.

`IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL` - if header exists change returned size of file.

`IRP_MJ_CREATE` - if header doesn't exists prepened header to file.

This works well, except on MS Word 2003 documents (doc,xls,ppt) and notepad.
I just seem to not catch some of the read and write operations and notepad shows the header as well as the file.

I have read A LOT in http://www.osronline.com/ and every one who asks there is told to read some Nagar book or look at their archives (which are disaster to search in). I think I've read there everything related to my issue.

It seems notepad uses Memory Mapped files, Fast IO, Pagged IO and god knows what else.
I've tried to hook `NtMapViewOfSection`, `MapViewOfFile` and `MapViewOfFileEx` with mHook, but when I opened some file in notepad and tried to find the mapped data I had no luck (but I found every other byte that was mapped to the memory).

Then I read that what I'm trying to accomplish isn't possible with a hook, only with minifilter driver and from what I figgured I'm missing some flags to set.

I would really appriciate it if someone could just tell me what to do in order to catch notepad's operations.

here's some code example for read:

```
CONST FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION Callbacks[] = {
    { IRP_MJ_WRITE,
    0,
    PreWrite,
    PostWrite },

    { IRP_MJ_READ,
    0,
    PreRead,
    PostRead },

    { IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION,
    0,
    NULL,
    PostQueryInfo },

    { IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL,
    0,
    NULL,
    PostQueryDir },

    { IRP_MJ_CREATE,
    0,
    NULL,
    PostCreate },

    { IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END }
};

FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
    PreRead (
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID *CompletionContext
    )
{
    NTSTATUS status = 0;
    ULONG bytesRead;
    PVOID readBuffer;
    LARGE_INTEGER zero;
    zero.QuadPart = 0;

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(FltObjects);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Data);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(CompletionContext);

    if(Data->Iopb->Parameters.Read.MdlAddress != NULL){
        return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
    }

    if(!IsFileNeedProccessing(&FltObjects->FileObject->FileName, Data)){
        return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
    }


    readBuffer = ExAllocatePool(
        NonPagedPool,
        prefixSize);
    if(readBuffer == NULL)
    {
        return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
    }

    status = FltReadFile(
        FltObjects->Instance,
        FltObjects->FileObject,
        &zero,
        (ULONG)prefixSize,
        readBuffer,
        FLTFL_IO_OPERATION_DO_NOT_UPDATE_BYTE_OFFSET,
        &bytesRead,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    if(NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        if(IsBuffAPrefixOfBuffB(prefix, readBuffer, prefixSize, (SIZE_T)bytesRead))
        {
            Data->Iopb->Parameters.Read.ByteOffset.QuadPart += prefixSize;
            FltSetCallbackDataDirty(Data);
        }
    }
    ExFreePool(readBuffer);

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
}

 FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
    PostRead (
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_opt_ PVOID CompletionContext,
    _In_ FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags
    )
 {
    NTSTATUS status;
    ULONG bytesRead;
    PVOID readBuffer;
    FILE_STANDARD_INFORMATION info;
    LONGLONG* currOffset = &Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->CurrentByteOffset.QuadPart;
    LARGE_INTEGER zero;
    zero.QuadPart = 0;

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(CompletionContext);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Flags);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Data);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(FltObjects);

    if(Data->Iopb->Parameters.Read.MdlAddress != NULL)
    {
        return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
    }

    if(!IsFileNeedProccessing(&FltObjects->FileObject->FileName, Data))
    {
        return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
    }

    status = FltQueryInformationFile(
        FltObjects->Instance,
        FltObjects->FileObject,
        &info,
        sizeof(info),
        FileStandardInformation,
        NULL);

    if(NT_SUCCESS(status)
        && info.EndOfFile.QuadPart != *currOffset
        && *currOffset >= (LONGLONG)prefixSize)
    {
        readBuffer = ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool,
            prefixSize);
        if(readBuffer == NULL)
        {
            return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
        }

        status = FltReadFile(
            FltObjects->Instance,
            FltObjects->FileObject,
            &zero,
            (ULONG)prefixSize,
            readBuffer,
            FLTFL_IO_OPERATION_DO_NOT_UPDATE_BYTE_OFFSET,
            &bytesRead,
            NULL,
            NULL);

        if(NT_SUCCESS(status))
        {
            if(IsBuffAPrefixOfBuffB(prefix, readBuffer, prefixSize, (SIZE_T)bytesRead))
            {
                *currOffset -= prefixSize;
                FltSetCallbackDataDirty(Data);
            }
        }
        ExFreePool(readBuffer);
    }

    return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
 }
```

`IsFileNeedProccessing` checks for file name and requesting process. (Some app's could see the header)

I would really appriciate it if someone could just tell me what to do in order to catch notepad's operations.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not intercept calls where `Parameters.Read.MdlAddress != NULL`?  That seems wrong.

Comment: You are right! I'll check it out. Thnaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Harry jonhston pointed out your check of only intercepting IRPs with `MdlAddress == NULL` is incorrect.

```
if(Data->Iopb->Parameters.Read.MdlAddress != NULL)
{
    return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
}
```

Most likely notepad and MS Office application are failing due to this.

Few points more:

- You would have to handle Paging IO appropriately.
- `FltReadFile` should only be called IRQL `PASSIVE_LEVEL`.
- More importantly changing file size and keeping it transparent to windows filesystem and user is quite complex. Its recommended not to do so.
- To add special data for a file may be you are better of using [alternate data stream](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763).

Comment: Thank you for your input. `IsFileNeedProccessing` also checks if `IRQL == PASSIVE_LEVEL`. How do you suggest to handle Paging IO appropriately?

Comment: @gfgqtmakia I think you need to skip paging IO, as you may not get file name during that. Although I suggest to do some research figure out what exactly you will have to do.

Comment: I can get file name from The `FileObject` and `IoQueryFileDosDeviceName`. Pagging IO is MDL? can you explain this further please?

Comment: Getting file name from `FileObject` is not appropriate. I would suggest to read up documentation related to minifilters on MSDN and osronline.com. Explaining this in short answer is little difficult!

Comment: It doesn't necessarily has to be short. :-)